# Unable to interact with element after class change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im sure this is common problem when dealing with javascript, but I can't seem to find a solution for it.

Im trying to create two functions on a "card", but differentiated by a class of the state of the card.

One function to "start" the card and one function to "remove" the card. But when I start a card, Im not able to remove it with the same function.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wm99z4sj/)

**html**

```
<div class="card started">click to hide</div>
<div class="card not-started">click to start</div>
```

**js**

```
$(".card.not-started").on("click", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("not-started").addClass("started").html("click to hide");
});

$('.card.started').on("click", function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wm99z4sj/1/

```
$(document).on("click", ".card.not-started", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("not-started").addClass("started").html("click to     hide");
});

$(document).on("click",'.card.started', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Try it like this.
If you use the document as a parent it will look for elements of that class added at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification will solve this problem.

```
$(".card").on("click", function () {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.hasClass("not-started")){
        el.toggleClass("not-started started").html("click to hide");
    } else {
        el.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

This way you will always delegate a click handler on `.card` but depending on the class you give it, it changes the functionality.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/abnq7d05/)**

If you want to keep 2 separate functions you can delegate from `$(document.body)` or `$(".card").parent()` like so:

```
var parent = $(".card").parent();
parent.on("click", ".not-started", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("not-started started").html("click to hide");
});

parent.on("click", ".started", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/jw4mrdc5/)**